# How to GROUP BY and aggregate fields after JOINS in Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following data which I got from the following query:

|  | date | quantity | name | season_id | contract_id | signing_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-07-01 00:00:00 | 3 | John Doe | 4 | 3000 | 2016-10-20 |
| 2 | 2021-07-28 00:00:00 | 14 | John Doe | 5 | 3541 | 2021-01-28 |
| 3 | 2016-08-15 00:00:00 | 10 | John Doe | 5 | 3000 | 2016-10-20 |
| 4 | 2016-08-02 00:00:00 | 5 | John Doe | 5 | 1528 | 2016-03-02 |

```
WITH ws AS (select date, quantity,
name, season_id, contract_id, contract.signing_date
FROM warehouse_state
JOIN inventory ON inventory.id = warehouse_state.inventory_id
JOIN owner ON owner.inventory_id = warehouse_state.id
JOIN season ON season.id = owner.season_id
JOIN contract ON contract.id = warehouse_contract.contract_id
GROUP BY date, quantity, name, season.id, contract.id, signing_date)
```

Now, I am having trouble aggregating the `ws` records based on dates.

Let's say I want a SUM of `quantity` grouped by `date` where `date` is date before contract `signing_date`. Not sure how to proceed with this, and probably it can be done in a single query without having a `WITH x AS` query or something actually using it like:

```
SELECT * FROM ws
LEFT JOIN contract on contract.contract_id = ws.contract_id
-- Here set following condition: for any ws record that has `date` before `signing_date`, SUM quantity and return aggregate
```

Expected output:

| contract_id | signing_date | quantity | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3000 | 2016-10-20 | 18 | John Doe |
| 3541 | 2021-01-28 | 18 | John Doe |
| 1528 | 2021-01-28 | 0 | John Doe |

In the expect output `quantity` is a SUM, and the record is grouped by contract. In the first record, #1, #3, and #4 were aggregated because their `date` values are before the contract (3000) `signing_date`. Even though, the 4th record does not have the same `contract_id`, it's also aggregated because its date field is before the signing date in contract 3000. Similarly, when grouped by contract 3541, record #2 is excluded from the aggregation because its `date` value is not before the `signing_date` of contract 3541.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You should just use `HAVING` clause as it will apply the search condition for your group.

Comment: Add your expected output

Comment: Completely forgot. Thanks @DineshDB

Answer (score 1):

Does that SQL really compile?  Reason is I see you referencing an inventory table that I don't see anywhere.

Also you are grouping on all columns -- essential a "select distinct."  Is that what you meant to do?

That aside, assuming your joins are correct and a couple of other assumptions, I'm going to sub them all with "< your tables and joins >."  I think all you want is a simple aggregate.  No need for a CTE (with clause).

```
select
  date, sum (quantity)
FROM
  < your tables and joins >
where
  date < signing_date
GROUP BY
  date
```

Alternatively, you can see the total quantity for all dates AND the total quantity before the contract date using a filter:

```
select
  date, sum (quantity) as total_quantity,
  sum (quantity) filter (where date < signing_date) as qty_before_contract_sign
FROM
  < your tables and joins >
GROUP BY
  date
```

If you wanted to see the other columns as well, then you want a windowing function.  Let me know if that's the case and I can demonstrate.

-- EDIT 9/7/22 --

Based on your update, I think this is what you want:

```
select
  contract_id, contract.signing_date, sum (quantity) as quantity,
  name
FROM warehouse_state
JOIN inventory ON inventory.id = warehouse_state.inventory_id
JOIN owner ON owner.inventory_id = warehouse_state.id
JOIN season ON season.id = owner.season_id
JOIN contract ON contract.id = warehouse_contract.contract_id
where
  date < contact.signing_date
GROUP BY
  contract_id, contract.signing_date, name
```

But the one gotcha is Contract 1528 will not show up in this output since it's filtered out by the where condition.

I'm not fond of this, but you could keep the filter to overcome this...  maybe there's a better solution.

```
select
  contract_id, contract.signing_date,
  coalesce (sum (quantity) filter (where date < contact.signing_date), 0) as quantity,
  name
FROM warehouse_state
JOIN inventory ON inventory.id = warehouse_state.inventory_id
JOIN owner ON owner.inventory_id = warehouse_state.id
JOIN season ON season.id = owner.season_id
JOIN contract ON contract.id = warehouse_contract.contract_id
GROUP BY
  contract_id, contract.signing_date, name
```

Also, my output does not match yours, but I'm hoping that's because of sample data.

Comment: Thanks, I had missed `inventory` in the join.

Comment: I see, this is useful! But the only thing is that I need to group by contract. I just added the expected output in the question. Let me know if you can adjust your answer to that

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  Second attempt posted...